# How can I propagate mousemove events from inside a bootstrap tooltip to an svg element at the same position

Tags: jquery, svg, d3.js, bootstrap-5

I have an svg element containing a circle element. I've attached a bootstrap tooltip to my circle element using body as its container so that the tooltip displays properly. The SVG has a mousemove event which captures all mouse movements in its bounding rect.

I would like the SVG to still receive these mousemove events when the mouse pointer s inside a tooltip displayed over the SVG. However my tooltip is not propogating these events to the SVG, and when the mouse is inside the tooltip, a 'mouseleave' event is being sent to the SVG which is not what I want.

I tried alternatively attaching the mousemove event to $(document) like

```
$(document).on('mousemove', $('#hover-circle'), function() {...} );
```

but this still doesn't receive mousemove events when pointer is inside tooltip.

At this point, I'm thinking of capturing mousemove events inside the tooltip and manually
passing them on to the SVG, however I'd rather not do this.

```
var svg = d3.select(panel[0]).append("svg")
    .attr("width", "100%")
    .attr("height", "100%")
    .on("mousemove", function() { 
       console.log('test');
    });

const hoverCircle = svg.append("g")
    .append("circle")
    .attr("id", "hover-circle")
    .attr("r", 3)
    .attr("cx", xScale(closestIndex))
    .attr("cy", yScale(dataset[closestIndex].y))
    .attr("title", dataset[closestIndex].evalStr)
    .tooltip({
         container: 'body',
         trigger: 'manual'
      })
    .tooltip('show');
```

Answer (score 1):

I've come up with a possible solution to this now using

`$('.tooltip').css('pointer-events', 'none');`

This causes mouse events to pass through the absolute positioned tooltip to an underlying element. Seems to be compatible with most browsers these days.

Comment: I was just about to update my answer with this. I think it's a good solution.